# Load balancer for multiple site in different port without host in docker with traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

Suppose I have two web service say they are `w1` and `w2` which are deployed by docker-compose.

Now I want to create multiple container for each of them, and create a load balancer in front of them which can make the services accessed by this:

```
http://localhost:8880 //for service w1

http://localhost:8888 //for service w2
```

I have searched, and I got [dockercloud-haproxy](https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-haproxy) and [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy).

However, the former is deprecated, and the later have to be used with hostname to distinguish different service.

It is kind of complicated for set different hosts especially in development environment.

Then I found traefik. Seems like more configurable. This is the config file I used:

```
version: "3"
services:
    w1:
      image: jwilder/whoami
      labels:
        - "traefik.backend=whoami"
        - "traefik.protocol=http"
        - "traefik.port=8080"
        - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http_8080"

    w2:
      build: .  # a simple node server which use port 80
      labels:
        - "traefik.backend=node"
        - "traefik.protocol=http"
        - "traefik.port=80"
        - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http_80"

    lb:
      image: traefik
      command: "--docker \
                --logLevel=DEBUG \
                --entryPoints='Name:http_80 Address::80' \
                --entryPoints='Name:http_8080 Address::8080'"
      ports:
        - 8880:80
        - 8888:8080
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

While it still can not meet my requirement.

Is this possible or any other alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the matcher `-"traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/"` under w1 and w2. Otherwise it defaults to `Host:w1.project_name`.

Also, I believe jwilder/whoami uses the port 8000 instead of 8080, so change `- "traefik.port=8080"` to `- "traefik.port=8000"`

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try.